# Timer was null. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

Well,
I'm trying to make an timer which will close the app after 10sec. but i'm just almost started to learn c#, also sorry for my english. So when i make the

```
Timer7.start();
Timer7.Enabled();
Timer7.Interval = 10000; //10sec.?
```

And the Timer7 meaning.

```
private void timer7_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //po nebuvimo intiko close app
    Application.Exit();
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    timer7.Stop();
}
```

And I do get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image]

Comment: has the `timer7` variable exist?

Comment: Application.Exit(); should be last line

Comment: When do you initialize `Timer7`?

Comment: What do you mean intialize?

Comment: This [MSDN article on Timer will be your best help - Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7). it includes an example of how to setup and use the Timer, and also how to act when the Timer event fires.

Comment: Where do you define `Timer7` and set it to an instance of whichever type it is declared as?

Comment: I created The Timer7 in the form

Comment: I have about 20 timers done, in other forms, but they do work fine, i don't know whats the reason now.

Comment: @ByByUostykLoxas think you will have to post more code - are you trying to do this in another class or in the class of the Form istelf? (can't see anything on the screenshot)